# test custom beam image locally before using dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a custom beam image that I ran with dataflow runner v2. Is there a way to quickly test it locally (to make sure that workers would run as expected on dataflow)?

Answer (score 1):

You can test it locally using https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#testing-locally
If you use GPUs, you can check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-gpus#building_a_custom_container_image and https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/develop-with-gpus

Comment: Does the `PortableRunner` work for custom containers? What should I put as the `END_POINT`?

Comment: Check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/#running-pipelines. You could use `embed` or run the local service with your Docker image as your `END_POINT`.

Comment: It works. Thanks! Some follow-up questions for this embed PortableRunner:

1. The container will not have access to local file system so for any input/output I should use gcs. Is that right?

2. Is there only 1 worker/container? Can it support parallelism as in DirectRunner (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/#parallel-execution)?

3. Where can I find good documentations for (embed) PortableRunner?

Comment: 1. you can mount any local directory to the container. 2. I do not think it can scale up using more than one container since it is for testing. 3. We dont have the good documentations but https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability/ and https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/sdk-harness-config/ could contain more information. You could read the source code. If you have some ideas to improve this, you are welcome to contribute.